# How to give access to another one of the VM created by App Engine?

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, websecurity

I have an web app (ReactJS) deployed in Google App Engine.

**Problem:**
The web app needs to be passed to security audit. Now they are asking for the internal network configuration of the VM where the app is deployed so that they can access the VM and perform greybox testing.

Note: *Greybox testing is the combination of whitebox and blackbox testing where some of the internal structure of the application is known.*

Comment: can you check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/access-control)

Comment: I checked this and we can follow this to deploy the app obviously. But they need an access to VM I guess. They must have the right to edit the code and view the logs.

Answer (score 0):

With GAE flexible, you can ssh to a deployed instance.  You can provide them with access credentials and instructions to ssh to deployed instances.

With GAE standard, you cannot ssh to a deployed instance.

For both, the VMs are maintained and updated by Google.  The testers should be able to review GAE documentation to address their security concerns.